# Shiv'a Veshiv'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred seventy-seven?

### ?שבעה ושבעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 277.

I see no need to seed this particular entry with a lazy gematria.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred seventy-six entries in this ongoing series.

Comment: "No need to seed etc." - sharp!!!

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106297/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Rebbi in [Sanhedrin 17b](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3644&size=1)-18a, a town must have a minimum of 277 residents in order to be fit for the formation of a Sanhedrin court. See Rashi there (top of [18a](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3645&size=1)) for the details about how this number is derived.